# How to use namelist in vxml

Tags: vxml

How to use **namelist** in vxml:

```
<field name="dtmf">
            <option dtmf="1" value="1"/>
            <option dtmf="2" value="2"/>
            <option dtmf="2" value="3"/>
            <filled>
                <submit next="{url3}" namelist="action toneId dtmf" method="get"/>
            </filled>
</field>
```

The above shows the `filled` section in vxml file with `namelist`, what does it mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351207/how-to-concat-varible-in-vxml); it gives details on how to use namelist.

As for *why* you should use namelist: namelist passes key/value pairs to the web service you access via `<submit>`. As with any other web service, the web service can use those key/value pairs to decide what response to send you.

As a concrete example, the web service might dynamically generate VoiceXML that contains annoucenements and options based on the values it receives.

Answer (score 0):

If the toneId is a session ID or a user ID, it could be better to use the POST method.

The GET can generate a cache entry, with the POST there is no cache (with GET you can set HTTP headers too, but some VoiceXML interpreter as our Voximal, creates the cache entry before generating the request...).